# Edit/Save not working in AdminBro using expressjs

Tags: reactjs, express

So basically i implemented AdminBro in my express app. Everything works like it should work. Fetching resources works and deleting resources works. However when i try to update/save and Create my resource it's not working, so basically every POST request that adminBro does it isn't working. It shows infinite loop and in mean time it will show:
POST /admin/api/resources/Athlete/records/5f09bd0e340546425fea51da/edit 500 120005.941 ms - 55

```
**Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/blagoj/Desktop/bbds/server/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:122:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:532:9)
    at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:525:3)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:672:12)**
```

console logs:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/admin/api/resources/Athlete/records/5f09bd0e340546425fea51da/edit net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Here's my code:
**admin.router.js**

```
const AdminBro = require('admin-bro');
const AdminBroExpress = require('@admin-bro/express');
const AdminBroMongoose = require('@admin-bro/mongoose');

AdminBro.registerAdapter(AdminBroMongoose);

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const adminBro = new AdminBro({
  databases: [mongoose],
  rootPath: '/admin',
  branding: {
    companyName: 'Fitness Documentation Site',
  }});

const router = AdminBroExpress.buildRouter(adminBro);
module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**:

```
const admin = require('./routes/admin');
app.use('/admin', admin);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with some of my middlewares inside main server.js file. So best way to fix this is to comment all your middlewares except adminBro and uncomment one by one and see what causes the problem.